# "Running the app on iPhone 7"

Tags: swift, xcode

I've tried to create an Apple Watch app for my app but I deleted it. 
Now when I want to build and run the app it says "Running [nameOfMyApp] on iPhone 7" but the app stays stuck on the latest version I've run. What's the problem ? How can I solve it ?

Comment: A few things you can try: 1) Clean your project 2) rebooting all devices 3) rebooting the development machine...

Comment: Try resetting your simulator.